# Replace 0 with non-0 value corresponding to the key column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2022-09-09', '2022-09-12', '2022-09-12', '2022-09-12', '2022-09-13'],
                  'B' : ['2022-09-01', '2022-09-02', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-04', '2022-09-05'],
                  'C' : [4701.80, 0, 12571.13, 0, 3011.06]})
```

[image]

I would like to fill in 0 values with the non-0 values as per key date in column A so the result would be :
[image]
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can apply a `ffill`/`bfill` per group using [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df['C'] = (df['C'].mask(df['C'].eq(0))
           .groupby(df['A'], group_keys=False)
           .apply(lambda s: s.ffill().bfill())
          )
```

output:

```
            A           B         C
0  2022-09-09  2022-09-01   4701.80
1  2022-09-12  2022-09-02  12571.13
2  2022-09-12  2022-09-03  12571.13
3  2022-09-12  2022-09-04  12571.13
4  2022-09-13  2022-09-05   3011.06
```

If you have a unique non-zero value per group, an alternative would be to use [`groupby.transform('first')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['C'] = (df['C'].mask(df['C'].eq(0))
           .groupby(df['A'], group_keys=False)
           .transform('first')
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# change the zero to null, to aid in making use of [fillna][1]
df['C']=df['C'].mask(df['C'].eq(0))

#do a groupby on 'A' and then do a ffill and bfill
df['C']=df.groupby(['A'])['C'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method='ffill').bfill() )
df
```

```
A   B   C
0   2022-09-09  2022-09-01  4701.80
1   2022-09-12  2022-09-02  12571.13
2   2022-09-12  2022-09-03  12571.13
3   2022-09-12  2022-09-04  12571.13
4   2022-09-13  2022-09-05  3011.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it using `groupby` and `transform`,

```
df['C']=df.groupby('A')['C'].transform(lambda s: s[s.ne(0).idxmax()])
```

**Full Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['2022-09-09', '2022-09-12', '2022-09-12', '2022-09-12', '2022-09-13'],
                  'B' : ['2022-09-01', '2022-09-02', '2022-09-03', '2022-09-04', '2022-09-05'],
                  'C' : [4701.80, 0, 12571.13, 0, 3011.06]})

df['C']=df.groupby('A')['C'].transform(lambda s: s[s.ne(0).idxmax()])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
            A           B         C
0  2022-09-09  2022-09-01   4701.80
1  2022-09-12  2022-09-02  12571.13
2  2022-09-12  2022-09-03  12571.13
3  2022-09-12  2022-09-04  12571.13
4  2022-09-13  2022-09-05   3011.06
```